# Could anyone help me identify what this is? Mold? Efflorescence?

Tags: walls, windows, paint, mold

I was cleaning and noticed this today. I am going to go to contact building management and see how best get started handling this as soon as I can (I'm in a co-op). I don't know what this stuff is but it's really worrying me. In the first picture it's eating away at the window frame (the peeling paint was already like that, the issue is the white crystal-like substance in the corner.

Then further down there's more stuff on the wall and I'm not sure if it's related but some of the paint is bubbling though it seems there that what's behind it is just the previous layer of paint.

I'm really kicking myself here - it's my bedroom and I mostly just sleep in here and I like it dark so I keep my curtains closed 24/7, otherwise I may have noticed this earlier. I should probably just stay calm until Monday but here I am searching stuff on the internet because I'm weak.

[image: first picture]

[image: further down]

Answer (score 3):

The top pic shows the results of a water leak that has caused the oxidation of the aluminium window frame. It is the aluminium version of rust.

The second pic is also from a water leak. The pic is too close to be able to tell more. Details of the location are not present.  However it also looks to be the result of water infiltration.

I do not believe either is dangerous unless you make a decision to ingest it.

Have the building super find the leak and cure that issue.  Then clean up the flakes, and do any sanding, scraping and repainting needed.

Comment: The top pic looks to me like the damage may be caused by condensation. Look at the window each morning, when you get up. Mop up any condensation or improve the ventilation (or consider installing a dehumidifier).

Comment: Thanks, I hope this is all it is! Management emailed me back, the building is doing facade work and also thinks it is likely water infiltration.